# Access denied when my servlet tries to SSH from Tomcat

Tags: tomcat, servlets

I've written a Servlet that uses the library ganymed-ssh2-build210.jar (it uses these classes: import ch.ethz.ssh2.Connection; import ch.ethz.ssh2.Session; import ch.ethz.ssh2.StreamGobbler;) to run commands over an SSH connection (for test purposes it connects to my local machine).  When I run my class as a standalone app it works, but when I deploy it into Tomcat and Tomcat starts it up as a Servlet, I get this exception (I've cut off the end, as I figured it probably wasn't relevent, but I can include it all if that would help):

```
java.security.AccessControlException: access denied (java.net.SocketPermission 127.0.0.1:22 connect,resolve)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(AccessControlContext.java:323)
    at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(AccessController.java:546)
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(SecurityManager.java:532)
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkConnect(SecurityManager.java:1034)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:513)
    at ch.ethz.ssh2.transport.TransportManager.establishConnection(TransportManager.java:340)
    at ch.ethz.ssh2.transport.TransportManager.initialize(TransportManager.java:448)
    at ch.ethz.ssh2.Connection.connect(Connection.java:643)
    ...
```

Is this perhaps something to do with security policies?  If so, do you know how I change them?

I'm using Java 1.6 and Tomcat6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you running Tomcat with the -security argument turned on?  If so, you need to edit $CATALINA_BASE/conf/catalina.policy and allow ch.ethz.ssh2.transport access to java.net.Socket.

Comment: Sorry to sound like a noob, but what would that entry look like?  I've just tried the following (I copied the jar example from local.policy), but to no avail:

grant codeBase "jar:file:${catalina.base}/webapps/GetSpinData/WEB-INF/lib/ganymed-ssh2-build210.jar!/-"{
     permission java.net.SocketPermission "127.0.0.1:22", "connect";
};

Comment: I added the following to catch everything:

grant codeBase "jar:file:${catalina.base}/webapps/GetSpinData/WEB-INF/lib/ganymed-ssh2-build210.jar!/-"{
        permission java.security.AllPermission;
};
grant codeBase "file:${catalina.base}/webapps/GetSpinData/WEB-INF/lib/-"{
        permission java.security.AllPermission;
};
grant codeBase "file:${catalina.base}/webapps/GetSpinData/WEB-INF/classes/-"{
        permission java.security.AllPermission;
};

It works, thanks! :D

How would I narrow it down to just the permissions I need?  And is that the right file, or should it be in local.policy?

Comment: Keep it in catalina.policy, don't change local.policy.  I believe the startup scripts/batch files pass the path to this file in to the security manager when tomcat starts up.

I'm not really sure how to narrow this down to the specific permissions you need.  I hate to dish you off to a link, but if you look at http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/guide/security/permissions.html, this will give you (probably more than enough) information you need to nail down the exact permissions.  My guess is you will want to look at the NetPermission and SocketPermission.  Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like java is getting access denied on port 22 - are you sure you're trying to connect as a client, and not spawn a server?  If it was trying to bind a listener to port 22, you're likely to get an error unless you're running as a superuser.

Comment: Definitely connects as a client, it runs fine as a standalone app.